# TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I need help with my code. I am building discord bot. I don't know what's wrong with my code, but it gives

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

```
if(receivedMessage.content.startsWith("!")) {
    processCommand(receivedMessage)
}

function processCommand(receivedMessage) {
    let fullCommand = receivedMessage.content.substr(1)
    let splitCommand = fullCommand.split(" ")
    let primaryCommand = splitCommand[0]
    let arguments = splitCommand.slice(1)

    if (primaryCommand == "help") {
        helpCommand(arguments, receivedMessage)
    }
}


function helpCommand(arguments, receivedMessage){
    if (arguments.length == 0) {
        receivedMessage.channnel.send("Im not sure what are you looking for.Try 
using `!help [topic]`")
    } else {
        receivedMessage.channel.send("It looks like you need help with " + arguments)
    }
}
```

Comment: receivedMessage.channnel is undefined...

Comment: You published your login token, you should've never done it: everyone that has it can login into the account and do whatever they want with the bot. I've hidden it from the post, but it's not invisible: you should create a new one from your bot's page from [Discord's developers' portal](https://discordapp.com/developers/applications/): bot -> regenerate

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined` tells you that `receivedMessage.channnel` is undefined, when then looking closer in the line:

```
  receivedMessage.channnel.send("Im not sure what are you looking for.Try using `!help [topic]`")
```

you should notice that you did `cha`**`nnn`**`el` instead of `channel`

Comment: im new to coding so..my self awareness is kind of dull.Thanks a lot for the response

Comment: If the answer is eneugh then you can use the green tick on the left of it to mark your question as answered